# How do you access static variables in the Global object

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

So I have created a global class which extends globalsettings:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
private Thread thread = new Thread();

@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    ....
public void write(byte[] bytes) {
    ....
```

Which has a Thread in it as I am listening to a socket, so I need it up and running all the time. I tried to use Actors and had a class that extends UntypedActor but it seemed to be very hackish and I had to at the end of the call to the actor make it call itself.

I also need to write to the socket. which I have a method called write which writes to the socket. What I would like to do is from one of my methods call the global objects write method. Is there a way I can do this? Atm my Global object is not in a package. Do I need to put it into a package to get it to work?

Comment: I really got the impression, somewhere, something went terribly wrong when you designed the application. Part of the philosophy of play is asynchronous and stateless designing. You are doing all the contrary, first by sharing a variable across all requests and secondly by starting a thread...

Comment: Let me add, that Play is a web framework, if you are talking about web Sockets, there are better ways to handle them, if not you are indeed trying to hack something using the wrong tools.

Comment: I understand that Play framework is stateless. But you cant really have stateless sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved my problem using the singleton pattern. Created an object called ThreadSingleton so that I could access it from anywhere.

For more information check out this link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern